# Why is this not casting to long

Tags: java, casting

I got strange java casting problem today coming from such code

`new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31)`

This is supposed to give date 31 days before now, but returns date 16 days after. It obviously happens because 
`1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31`
is evaluated as Integer and overflows.

`new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31)`
works as expected

I think java should cast whole expression to Long because first operand is Long `System.currentTimeMillis()` but it's not happening here for some reason I don't understand. Is there some exception about hardcoded  constants to be int ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `LocalDateTime` provided by Java? With that it would simply be: `LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(31);`

Comment: Oh also to answer your  problem: All your numbers are integers, the `*` operator takes precedence over the `-` operator and so the conversion only happens after the overflow happened already.

Comment: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31` is an int. Then you subtract it from a long and get another long. But the int has already overflowed before the subtraction.

Comment: Now I got it, elementary school math, it's like `System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31)` for java

Comment: BODMAS - Bracket, Of, Division, Multiplication, Addition and Subtraction

Comment: Well that's defeating the symptom and not the cause but I guess.

Comment: @J_D What is "Of" supposed to mean in that sequence?

Comment: It means something to make the acronym pronounceable :-)  Actually, it means "orders"; i.e. powers, roots, etc

Comment: @StephenC I thought it should have been "orders". I was confused why someone would have it standing for "of".

Comment: https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html

Comment: @Ben Actually, **`LocalDateTime` is the wrong class** here, as it does not track points on the timeline, lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Instead, `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` is needed here. See [correct Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49780590/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s all been said, but I thought it deserved to go into an answer. Use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class with [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```
    ZonedDateTime aMonthAgo = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Indian/Comoro")).minusMonths(1);
```

Output on my computer just now (April 11):

> 2018-03-11T19:57:47.517032+03:00[Indian/Comoro]

I subtract a month, so that means 28, 29, 30 or 31 days depending on the month I’m in and the number of days in the previous month. If you want 31 days unconditionally, you can have that, of course:

```
    ZonedDateTime thirtyoneDaysAgo 
            = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Indian/Comoro")).minusDays(31);
```

Since there were 31 days in March, the result is the same in this case. It won’t always be.

I am using and recommending [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), the modern Java date and time API. It’s so much nicer to work with and much less error-prone than the outdated `Date` class.

### What went wrong in your code?

It’s about [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31` consists of `int` values. Yes, integer literals have type `int` unless they have the `L` suffix. Because multiplication is carried out before subtraction (as you had already expected), the result is an `int` too, but it overflows because the result would be greater than the maximum number that an `int` can hold. Unfortunately Java doesn’t inform you of the overflow, it just gives you a wrong result, here `-1616567296`, about -19 days. When subtracting these, you get a date and time about 19 days into the future.

As a habit, use parentheses, the `L` suffix, and [underscore-grouping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) for readability.

```
( System.currentTimeMillis() - ( 1_000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 31L ) )
```

If you wanted to be made aware of overflow, you may use `Math.multiplyExact​()` for your multiplications (since Java 8). Fortunately, the modern library classes save you completely from multiplying. And signal any overflow.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [`Math.multiplyExact​() documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-)