# add seconds to System.currentTimeMills()

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the time of 100 days from now using the following:

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 8640000 * 1000));
    }
}
```

It gives me back `Jan 04 08:57:25 UTC 2021` which is not correct. How should I remedy this?

Comment: Integer overflow.  8640000×1000 > 2³¹.  Change `8640000` to `8640000L` so Java knows you’re doing math with 64-bit `long` values, which will not overflow.

Comment: Also consider `LocalDateTime.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(100))`.

Comment: @trashgod Why `plus(Duration.ofDays(100))` when `plusDays(100)` is available?

Comment: While in UTC 100 days equals the number of milliseconds you try to calculalte, in very many other time zones it often is not the case since a day may be for example 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: @Andreas: Good question; I started to go that way, but I wanted to emphasize the notion of  `Duration`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323792/android-days-between-two-dates). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776292/why-is-this-not-casting-to-long)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (long)8640000 * 1000));
```

Or

```
System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 8640000L * 1000));
```

8640000 * 1000 is 8,640,000,000, which exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE of 2,147,483,647. You can solve this issue by casting it to a `long`.

This gives the result:

```
Tue Apr 13 15:26:10 EDT 2021
```

Answer (score 4):

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Change the ZoneId as per your requirement e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        LocalDate after100Days = today.plusDays(100);
        System.out.println(after100Days);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-04-13
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using the legacy API:**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Change the TimeZone as per your requirement e.g. TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London")
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 100);
        Date after100Days = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(after100Days);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Apr 13 19:40:11 BST 2021
```

Answer (score 3):

Try sometime like

```java
LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(100).toString()
```

or

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"); // you could used any format
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 100); // Adding 100 days
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: `c.setTime(new Date());` is redundant, since the `Calendar` object returned by [`getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--) is already the current time: *"Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The **Calendar returned is based on the current time** in the default time zone with the default FORMAT locale."*

Comment: Yes you are right, Just added it incase you want to reset the date. I have edited it