# convert exp date JWT token in java not work like in js, why?

Tags: javascript, java, datetime, jwt, java-time

I'm trying to get value of the `exp` datetime in a JWT token.
`exp` is the expiration time after which JWT must not be accepted.

In JavaScript I get the correct result by

```java
new Date(1661159784*1000)
```

the correct result is

```
Mon Aug 22 2022 11:16:24 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

---

Why didn't I get the same in Java?

Java:

```java
System.out.println(new Date(1661159784 * 1000));
```

result:

```
Sat Dec 20 13:17:20 CET 1969
```

The same result setting s UTC time zone:

```java
final ZonedDateTime exp2 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1661159784 * 1000)
                                  .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(exp2);
```

result:

```
1969-12-20T12:17:20.448Z
```

Comment: `1661159784 * 1000` as a signed 32bit int is `-992559552` ... try `new Date( -992559552 )` in JS and see!! - or `new Date((1661159784 * 1000) | 0)` in JS to do exactly what Java does - try `new Date(1661159784L * 1000L)` in Java

Comment: by the way, Java documents `new Date` as taking a LONG argument, not an int ... see, in Javascript, we have Number ... no int/long/float/double ... just Number ... which has a "safe" integer range of +/- 2**53 - 1 - a Java INT is only 32 bits ... and todays date needs 41? or so bits ... so, 53 is enough, 32 is not

Comment: note: I deliberately omitted any mention of BigInt in javascript as that is irrelevant :p

Comment: I am not sure why you want a `ZonedDateTime` in Java in this case. For most purposes an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime` should do fine. In any case use `Instant.ofEpochSecond(1661159784)` to start with (note *Second*  instead of *Milli*) and then do further conversion from there if necessary.

Comment: Somewhat similar: [Why is this not casting to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776292/why-is-this-not-casting-to-long)

Answer (score 4):

The [constructor of `Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) you used takes a `long` argument, but what you passed is in fact an (overflown) `int`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int overflowedInt = 1661159784 * 1000;
    System.out.println(overflowedInt);
}
```

Output: `-992559552`

The same applies to `Instant.ofEpochMilli(long)`…

---

You can get the desired result if you use `Instant.ofEpochSecond(long)` without multiplying by 1000:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1661159784L);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    System.out.println(zdt);
}
```

Output:

```
2022-08-22T09:16:24Z[UTC]
```

---

If you have to use a `java.util.Date`, which is not recommended anymore, either do the calculation with `long`s:

```java
System.out.println(new Date(1661159784L * 1000L));
```

or — **much better** — use the compatibility method `Date.from(Instant)` and create the `Instant` as shown at the top of this answer, that is `Instant.ofEpochSecond(long)`:

```java
System.out.println(Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1661159784L)));
```

Output:

```
Mon Aug 22 11:16:24 CEST 2022
```

… in my `TimeZone`/`ZoneId` ("Europe/Berlin"), pay attention to the zones here.